# When programs like awk gets an input through pipe, does it read it line by ine?

Tags: bash, unix, awk

So I usually perform unix task in the form of `cat text.csv | awk '{print $1}'` and the output is a results that are separated by newlines. I am wondering since cat outputs csv file (which I assume is done linearly), awk also processes the output line by line, performing linearly. I feel like it's obviously true, but given how bash commands are designed to be applied on multiple items, I was wondering if bash handles these commands differently than just reading line by line.

For example, I have two ways of writing my code:

```
while IFS=, read a b c
    echo $a $b $c
done < textfile.txt
```

OR

```
cat textfile.txt | awk '{print $1 $2 $3}'
```

Are they different in terms of running time or how it processes data?

Comment: One side of the pipe recieves all the output from the other in one chunk unless the command has something that tells it to act differently. awk in the example will recieve the entire file as a single stream of data and will the process it as though it were a file.

Comment: Can you expand on this part `but given how bash commands are designed to be applied on multiple items, I was wondering if bash handles these commands differently than just reading line by line.` What do you mean designed to ? Handles which commands differently than reading line by line ?

Comment: I think the difference between the snippets of code I posted was what I was looking for. I did not know pipe outputs its result as one chunk. When awk gets this chunk of input, I am assuming it processes in a linear fashion as in it starts at the beginning of input and finishes at the end of input? Sorry for confusing phrasing. i was just wondering if there was a special internal mechanism to process awk or grep more efficiently than linear fashion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both ways you write your code:

```
while IFS=, read a b c
    echo $a $b $c
done < textfile.txt

OR

cat textfile.txt | awk '{print $1 $2 $3}'
```

are wrong. The shell loop will be very slow and produce bizarre results based on the content of your input file. The correct way to write it to avoid the bizarre results is (you should arguably use `printf` instead of `echo` too):

```
while IFS=, read -r a b c
    echo "$a $b $c"
done < textfile.txt
```

but it'd still be incredibly slow. The shell is an environment from which to call tools with a language to sequence those calls, it is NOT a tool for text processing - the UNIX text-processing is awk.

The `cat | awk` command should be written as:

```
awk '{print $1, $2, $3}' textfile.awk
```

since awk is perfectly capable of opening files on it's own and NO UNIX command EVER needs `cat` to open the file for them, they can all either open the file themselves (`cmd file`) or have the shell open it for them `cmd < file`).

awk processes each input record one at a time, where an input record is any chunk of text separated by the value of awks `RS` variable (a newline by default). Doesn't matter how/where those records are coming from. The only thing you also [rarely] need to consider is buffering - see your awk and shell man pages for info on that.

One way to set shell variables from awk output:

```
$ cat file
the quick brown fox

$ array=( $(awk '{print $1, $2, $3}' file) )

$ echo "${array[0]}"                        
the
$ echo "${array[1]}"                        
quick
$ echo "${array[2]}"
brown
```

Set individual shell variables from the array contents if you like or just use the array.

Another way:

```
$ set -- $(awk '{print $1, $2, $3}' file)

$ echo "$1"
the
$ echo "$2"
quick
$ echo "$3"
brown
```

Comment: So if I pipe something like `ls` to awk, does awk process line by line since `RS` variable would be newline? Also, one reason why I chose while loop over awk was that I need all three variables to be used later as well, and I couldn't find an easy way of storing $1, $2, $3 into other variables.

Comment: 1) Yes. 2)  It is easy (I just showed 2 ways at the end of my answer) but usually when people are doing that it's because they have the wrong approach.

Comment: Can you explain why it's the wrong approach? I was thinking of changing my while read loop to awk one since you mentioned while loop can be incredibly slow.

Comment: It's not just incredibly slow it's also incredibly difficult to write robustly since parsing text is simply not what the shell is for. The shell is an environment from which to call tools to perform specific tasks and has a language to sequence those calls. The guys who wrote the shell also wrote awk to be the UNIX general purpose text processing tool. So, in a UNIX environment you never write shell loops just to process text, the shell just calls awk and awk does the rest. See http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice etc.

Comment: Oh - and it's usually wrong because usually people try to piece together small awk/sed/grep/etc. "one liners" with shell variables passing info around between them which is very inefficient and error prone. The time when it's NOT wrong is when the output of the awk script is a list of files to be created/removed/moved/modified or processes to be killed, etc. Even then creating a bunch of variables to do it is very often the wrong approach too vs, e.g. using `xargs`. Mainly though - if you're manipulating text just stay inside one awk script.

Answer (score 5):

It depends entirely on the thing 'reading' the pipe, how it handles it. By default *most* use `\n` as their 'record separator' so work line by line.

That's optional, but works in the majority of cases. The pipe itself doesn't have any such concept of record separator - you can send anything you like down it - even raw binary content.

e.g.

```
tar cvf - . | gzip -c | ssh $somehost "cat > file.tgz"
```

Edit: based on your update:

It doesn't matter how you write your code. Make it clear, clean and elegant and don't worry about efficiencies until you have to. This is often never, so any time spent optimising is wasted time.

The thing that takes more time than anything else is streaming data off disk - usually, anyway. You can't make that go any faster, so mostly - there's just no point worrying.

> "Premature optimisation is the root of all evil" - Donald Knuth

So write clear code, first, foremost and only. And if you *really* need to worry about performance, profile it and focus your efforts (and probably don't use shell)

Comment: Thank you. I added a bit more to better phrase my question.

Comment: You are right that performance optimization in bash usually does not yield any noticeable performance gain. Though, there exist some bad habits which should be avoided for the sake of performance and, maybe even more important, good style. `cat text.csv | awk '{print $1}'` for example is just bad. You do not need the `cat`. Just use `awk '{print $1} text.csv'` which is even shorter to type. Despite that, in this case `cut` would be the correct tool to use. While this is not a problem, in my opinion, you should still avoid such code.

Comment: Even useless uses of cat have "uses" IMO. `cat somefile | grep whatever` is (or at least _can be_) clearer than `grep something somefile` and the overhead is pretty mild.

Comment: @Sobrique - I strongly disagree that `cat somefile | grep whatever` is clearer than `grep something somefile` but that's probably just personal preference and/or what we're used to doing/seeing. I assume your thought process is that you want to read the data stream left-to-right and the usual response to anyone suggesting `cat somefile | grep whatever` is the way to do that is to use `< somefile grep something` - do you find that clearer than `grep something somefile` too (I don't but I'm just wondering).

Answer (score 1):

It partly depends on how the source code is written, but it is almost certainly using a buffered interface.  The size of that buffer depends how the pipe is used in the program, the C Runtime Library and the operating system in use.

Typically the constants used are `PIPE_SIZE` (BSD) and `PIPE_BUF` (POSIX).  Assuming a POSIX system, the minimum size is 512 bytes, but it could be 4096 bytes (which is a page size on a 32-bit machine).

The code itself might be using a higher level interface which slices on newlines, and the lower level will manage the buffer.  There are several ways to do that.

You compare pipes and file IO.  The overhead when using pipes in the way you show (particularly in bash) is that it runs each component in a child process.  Where bash IO is not particularly efficient, it is doubtful that it will be slower than creating child processes to run things like `cat`.

```
cat textfile.txt | awk '{print $1 $2 $3}'
```

Will create two child processes.  Although `cat` is very efficient, it is still an overhead.  Whether that overhead exceeds the inefficiencies of Bash file IO will be data dependant.  You really should benchmark it yourself with your own meaningful data (not trivial snippets).  However most would say that you should avoid unnecessary child processes.   See also [Useless use of cat award](http://www.smallo.ruhr.de/award.html)

The `read` command in bash has a number of complications which makes answering your question quite difficult.  There are differences depending on whether `read` is reading from a pipe, the command-line, or a file.  It even supports unbuffered input as well.  Also you can ignore the newline delimiters with:

```
read -N number_of_characters variable ....
```

and you can change the record delimiter so that it is not a newline:

```
read -d delimiter variable ...
```

The -d option causes read to continue until the first character of `delimiter` is read, rather than newline.

Comment: BASH While read will be slower than piping cat into awk for anything over around 40 lines, and even when its quicker the performance difference is negligible.

Comment: @User112638726 is correct. A bash while-read loop MAY be faster than awk for a tiny file where performance doesn't matter but for any large file where performance DOES matter a bash while-read loop will be massively slower than awk. Unless you're doing simple individual ops like using parameter substitution vs `echo | sed` (e.g. `x=abc; echo "${x##a}"` vs `x=abc; echo "$x" | sed 's/^a//'`) there is nothing wrong with spawning child processes - for anything other than trivial operations it's usually the best approach in every way over using bash builtins.